# parsing through an escape \n json and parsing through the data

Tags: javascript

So I have some data that has `\n` so I escaped them `replace`.  This is an example of the escape string.

```
132 Leo Lane Apt. 516\\nThe Colony, TX 76156\\nUS
```

What I am trying to do is remapped the data so I can break them apart into

Address
City
State
Zip
Country

whats the best ways to accomplish this?  The data I get back in returning initially is somewhat like this.

```
11 w 1120 ave.\nLombard, IL 12348\nUS
```

Comment: What you using to get the "data I get back"?

Comment: Try to avoid the double escape if you can - having to remember if data in a field is escaped or not is never the cleanest code. Secondly there are other escape sequences that can appear like `\t  \r \\ ` etc.

Comment: How is the data loaded initially? What do you get when you `console.log(data);`? Note that JSON is a special text format that looks like JS object literals. One way: https://jsfiddle.net/o5fgsrhp/

Comment: @ChrisG so the data is very inconsistent.   it has line breaks after the address, or sometimes after the state or sometimes is missing and just has `El Paso, TX 79922
\nUS`.  Trying to find out whats the best approach to take a map value of the given and separate it.

Comment: Address parsing can be such a pain. I use a service. Google map API or the like. They return a  result  you can reliably parse , plus the lat lng

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = `132 Leo Lane Apt. 516
The Colony, TX 76156
US`;
// or '132 Leo Lane Apt. 516\nThe Colony, TX 76156\nUS';

// Split by newlines
const [address, mixed, country] = input.split('\n');
console.log('address:', address); // '132 Leo Lane Apt. 516'
console.log('country:', country); // 'US'

// Parse the mixed line:
console.log('mixed:', mixed); // 'The Colony, TX 76156'

// OPTION 1: We can split by comma/space using regex:
const match = mixed.match(/^(.*), (\w+) (\d+)$/);
if (!match) throw new Error('Wrong format');
// Array deconstructuring but we skip match[0] with the leading comma
const [, city, state, zip] = match;
console.log('city:', city); // 'The Colony'
console.log('state:', state); // 'TX'
console.log('zip:', zip); // '76156' (as a string, not a number)

// OPTION 2: We can simply split by comma/space using .split:
const [city2, afterComma] = mixed.split(',');
console.log('city2:', city2); // 'The Colony'
console.log('afterComma:', afterComma); // ' TX 76156'
// We first .trim() `afterComma` to get rid of the leading space
const [state2, zip2] = afterComma.trim().split(' ');
console.log('state2:', state2); // 'TX'
console.log('zip2:', zip2); // '76156' (as a string, not a number)
```

Alternatively, you can have a big complex multiline RegExp to match everything at once, but at the cost of readability.

Mind that this is very strict about how your data is formatted though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that is completely consistent..

```
var initial_string = "11 w 1120 ave.\nLombard, IL 12348\nUS"
split_string = initial_string.split('\n')
address = split_string[0]
space_split = split_string[1].split(' ')
city = space_split[0].replace(',', '')
state = space_split[1]
zip = space_split[2]
country = split_string[2]
```